# MVVM startActivityForResult

Tags: android, mvvm

When a view is clicked, startActivityForResult should be called.
But I cannot call startActivityForResult in viewModel. How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 4):

I have read the google samples here (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvvm-databinding) and find the solution:

1. create a interface to implement:

   ```
   public interface TaskItemNavigator {
       void openTaskDetails(String taskId);
   }
   ```
2. have a weak reference in view model:

   ```
   @Nullable
   private WeakReference<TaskItemNavigator> mNavigator;
   ```
3. implement it in activity:

   ```
   public class TasksActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TaskItemNavigator{
       ...
       @Override
       public void openTaskDetails(String taskId) {
           Intent intent = new Intent(this, TaskDetailActivity.class);
           intent.putExtra(TaskDetailActivity.EXTRA_TASK_ID, taskId);
           startActivityForResult(intent, AddEditTaskActivity.REQUEST_CODE);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: This is a valid way to solve the problem, however the question is about solving it using the MVVM pattern. In MVVM, the view observes view model - view model does not have a reference to the view. Therefore the answer is not a valid approach if OP wants to use MVVM.

Comment: Sorry but this is absolutely not a clean way to achieve this

Comment: @issamux perhaps but if you don't go implementing something like SingleLiveEvent, this is probably the only correct way to do it.